# Making SSH terminate on error

Tags: ssh, openssh

I have a script that is causing a bunch of ssh -D (socks proxy) connections to open.  Sometimes one of them is trying to open on a port that is in use, in which case it prints an error.  Unfortunately, after printing the error it does not terminate but rather keeps running.  How can I tell SSH to terminate if it is unable to actually do what I'm asking it to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found it.  You pass

```
-o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes
```